# How to rewrite @ sign on Nginx?

Tags: regex, nginx

```
rewrite ^/@(.*)$ /user/$1/ last;
```

I want to rewrite foo.com/@bar to foo.com/user/bar.

Comment: This `^/@(.*)$` says beginning of string, forward slash, @ character, then capture optionally all characters past it to the end of string. So, the regex won't ever match the string `foo.com/@bar` Maybe if the `^` was left off it would. Or, this regex `^(.*)/@(.*)$` and replace with `$1/user/$2`

Comment: @x15, yes leaving `^` will fix the issue. Actually all OP has to do is remove that carrot `^` and his `regex` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an Nginx expert, but here is what you need to do

```
rewrite /@([^\W]+) /user/$1/ last;
```

to prove that, I have written a small `Javascript` code that demonstrates the `replace` part.

```
const url = "foo.com/@bar";                                                     

const result = url.replace(/@([^\W]+)/, "user/$1");

console.log(`the result is ${result}`);
```

Result

`the result is foo.com/user/bar`